# How can I get around this issue? Two animations on one element?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions, css-animations

So I'm trying to somehow do two animations on one element but I can't be able to fix it.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ZanicL3/9ckqb6t3/) which includes only the important things. For the full picture, [check here](http://googledoodle.lucasdebelder.be/). I want to make the alien which represents the letter L coming in from the right to left (= the position where he is now at).

**So what I want to get is that the alien moves from right to left, but together with the moving legs, and the image of the alien.**

I will explain some of the code.

**HTML**:

```
            <div class="letter_L">

                <div class="monster_L">
                    <img src="http://googledoodle.lucasdebelder.be/images/l/monster.png">
                </div>
                <div class="benen_L">
                    <div class="B_1"></div>
                    <div class="B_2"></div>
                    <div class="B_1 B_3"></div>
                    <div class="B_2 B_4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

`.monster_L` represents the **image of the alien**

`.Benen_L` represents the **legs** (=benen)

**CSS**

```
/*Monster L*/
.monster_L img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 296px;
    left: 596px;
    z-index: 50;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 70px;
}

/*Been1*/
.B_1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 293px;
    left: 597px;
    z-index: 40;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 8px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #297f40;
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;

    animation-name: animation_B_1;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
/*Been2*/
.B_2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 286px;
    left: 605px;
    z-index: 40;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 8px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #297f40;
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;

    animation-name: animation_B_2;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
/*Been3*/
.B_3 {
    left: 613px;
}
/*Been4*/
.B_4 {
    left: 621px;
}
@keyframes animation_B_1 {
    0%{ bottom: 293px; }
    50% { bottom: 286px; }
    100%{ bottom: 293px; }
}
@keyframes animation_B_2 {
    0%{ bottom: 286px; }
    50% { bottom: 293px; }
    100%{ bottom: 286px; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply `position: absolute` to `letter_L` and apply a `keyframe` to it for its translation with the `right` property.

However when you apply `position: absolute` or `position: relative` to `letter_L`, all `position: absolute` elements inside are not going to be relative to `letter_L`. So you have change the `top`, `bottom`, `left` coordinates accordingly.

I have tried to solve this for you.

Check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/9ckqb6t3/3/).

Refer code:

```css
.letter_L {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  /* z-index: 100000000; */
  height: 90px;
  animation-name: moveRTL;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


/*Monster L*/

.monster_L img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 70px;
}


/*Been1*/

.B_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 40;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 8px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #297f40;
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
  animation-name: animation_B_1;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


/*Been2*/

.B_2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 8px;
  z-index: 40;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 8px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #297f40;
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
  animation-name: animation_B_2;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


/*Been3*/

.B_3 {
  left: 16px;
}


/*Been4*/

.B_4 {
  left: 24px;
}

@keyframes animation_B_1 {
  0% {
    top: 28px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 32px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 28px;
  }
}

@keyframes animation_B_2 {
  0% {
    top: 32px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 28px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 32px;
  }
}

@keyframes moveRTL {
  0% {
    right: 0;
  }
  100% {
    right: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- L letter -->
<div class="letter_L">
  <div class="monster_L">
    <img src="http://googledoodle.lucasdebelder.be/images/l/monster.png">
  </div>
  <div class="benen_L">
    <div class="B_1"></div>
    <div class="B_2"></div>
    <div class="B_1 B_3"></div>
    <div class="B_2 B_4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```